# Display an image from a query string

Tags: php, html

I'm working on a project in `PHP`. Trying to load an image from a query string like so => `<img src="load_image.php?name=Profile_Photo_Small" />`

Anybody know how to do this?

Comment: have the `load_image.php` file return the image, using `file_get_contents` for instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `load_image.php` file, you need to return your file with qualified headers. something like:

```
$filename = __DIR__ . '/images/' . $_GET['name'] . '.jpg';
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
readfile($filename);
```

I should also warn you about using query string parameters in your code directly. You need to clean your input data.

Comment: Just becareful that this way will make you **lose the benefits of caching**, you are uploading the image every time the PHP script is called, you either handle the cache headers sent by the browser, or redirect the request to the image file and let Apache handle caching

Comment: Do I have to echo it out? Like ```echo readfile($filename);```

Comment: `readfile()` returns the number of bytes read from the file on success, or FALSE on failure, the function reads a file and writes it to the output buffer,  so you don't _echo it out_. See [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: @AccountantمHow do I handle the cache headers sent by the browser